# In fullCalendar library, I am not able to control the vertical spacing between two events in a day grid cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar within my React application.
And I'm rendering my own custom react events in place of the default look (in my month view). I want to control the vertical spacing or say margin between two events. But I'm not able to do so. I checked the CSS which is getting applied and found that events have before and after pseudo classes with below css properties and values :

```
.fc-daygrid-event-harness:after, 
.fc-daygrid-event-harness:before {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

[image]
Not sure, but I think the display: table is setting some extra space around the events as when I tried to set content: none or display: flex, it got removed and all the events in a day cell stacked vertically over each other without any space between them.

As I need to control the vertical spacing between the events, I tried to add some css properties on this class : .fc-daygrid-event-harness but it didn't work in case of events which span for multiple days. I found that fullCalendar is styling them dynamically by setting position as absolute and specifying top/left/right properties. (Below is the attached screenshot for this)

[image]

I want to know how can I control the vertical spacing between the events. Also Is the above way of removing the extra space coming on the events, is a good approach ? Could it have any major side effects on any other functionality of fullCalendar ? Please suggest.

Regards

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the detailed explanation but if you can make an online demo where people can play around and debug your code, it can help you get an answer.

Comment: Why you are you just not styling fullCalendar events, instead of trying to put your own onto the grid? That is always going to cause layout issues I guess, and it also negates a lot of the benefits and features of fullCalendar. Unless by `rendering my own custom react events` you just mean changing the CSS of them? Either way,  you need to provide a [mre] of the issue in your question before we can help you realistically. With only the small CSS snippet you've shown here, I couldn't reproduce the issue: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/BaGzxZN